# Rendering HTML and CSS in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

if I Have a controller with a scope

```js
$scope.post.description = "<style>#bo{font-weight:bold}</style> <h5 id='bo'> HI</h1> <p>My name is bamidele</p>";
```

How can i render this in a view . it should render both html and css

I tried

$sce.trustAsCss($sce.trustAsHtml($scope.post.description));

but it didnt work

Comment: `but it didnt work` is not a proper problem description. Should explain what does or doesn't happen and what errors occur

Answer (score 0):

Please check this working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Guj3AuNrNNZ5F9EzkUxz?p=preview

Download file - angular-sanitize.js and include it in your app.

JS -

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngSanitize"]);       

app.controller('myController', function($scope,$compile) {
   $scope.html = '<p class="text-color">Your html code</p>';
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
         <p ng-bind-html="html"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.text-color {
    color: #0000CC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your description is bind to `$scope`, you normally be able to access it in the view with the double curly braces notation `{{}}`  :

```
<p> {{post.description}} </p> 
<!-- will generate "<style>#bo{font-weight:bold}</style> <h1 id='bo'> HI</h1> <p>My name is bamidele</p>"" -->
<!-- Note : you started with a h5 tag but closed with a h1 tag in your question -->
```

It will be way more cleaner and best practice if you separate style, logic and content :

**controller.js** :

```
controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.description =  '<h5 id='bo'> HI</h5> <p>My name is bamidele</p>';
}])
```

**style.css** :

```
#bo{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**view.html** :

```
{{post.description}} // will generate <h5 id='bo'> HI</h5> <p>My name is bamidele</p>
```